# I need to get jquery this.val() value into PHP at runtime

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Is there a way to get the jquery `this.val()` read into PHP at runtime?

I have a dynamic push of data and need to run a SQL statement that depends on the jquery value of `this.val()` - so something like

```
<?php $sql = "select * from table where id = " . this.val(); ?>
```

Comment: What is `this`?

Comment: PHP code is executed on the server **before** the HTML and JavaScript is sent to the **browser** where the JavaScript is executed. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/q/13840429/218196 (which also tells you how to solve your problem).

Comment: Post JS variable to PHP file with ajax and get the variable there with a $_POST request and use it in your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, becouse PHP can't read user's DOM.
You need to make an ajax request to send the data to the server.
[jquery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)